# How to forecast using short data set?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, mathematical-statistics, forecasting, prediction

I would like to forecast for next 2 months using 1 year data captured at monthly level.

sample of the data

1. 201702  7
2. 201703  1344
3. 201704  1311
4. 201705  2645
5. 201706  8581
6. 201707  7271
7. 201708  11550
8. 201709  11372
9. 201710  7089
10. 201711 10677
11. 201712 9147
12. 201801 2992

first column indicated month, second column indicates demand of product. I have used time series like arima, ets, ma all of them over fit. 
Can you suggest some basic models that may solve the problem?

Thanks